# How Can I Make Some Window Region Transparent?

Tags: autohotkey

Instead of making a window transparent, I just want to make some regions of it transparent, how can I achieve that?

Comment: The first thing to try is googling for the existing solutions, for example: [this one](http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/7377-create-a-transparent-circle-in-window-w-winset-region/?p=45417). Then try to adapt it and update the question with the specific details about the problem along with the code.

Comment: Ty for your reply, clearly your googling skills are better than mine. Again ty  :)

Answer (score 0):

Searching for:
AutoHotkey transparent - Google Search
https://www.google.com/#q=AutoHotkey+transparent

The first result is:
WinSet
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm

The subcommand 'Region' changes which parts
of the window are visible, making some parts completely transparent (invisible and click-through),
but it is not at all obvious from the help documentation that this is what it does.

Here is an example:

```
;make a Notepad window transparent apart from 3 opaque square regions:
vSquare1 := "100-100 200-100 200-200 100-200 100-100"
vSquare2 := "400-100 500-100 500-200 400-200 400-100"
vSquare3 := "700-100 800-100 800-200 700-200 700-100"
WinSet, Region, % vSquare1 " " vSquare2 " " vSquare3, Untitled - Notepad
```

There are further examples on the page.

Comment: He wanted to make some region**s** of it transparent. That docs page states: "Changes the shape of a window to _be_  _the_ specified rectangle, ellipse, or polygon." There is only one region the docs refer to, so from that we may infer that other methods are required to make a window into two or more rectangles, ellipses, or polygons.

Comment: The documentation is imperfect. I've added an example. Do post here if you wish to: [Suggestions on documentation improvements](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewforum.php?f=86).